# Configuring a JComboBox in a Metro Style

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a screen that follows a Metro Style. But I'm not changing the Look and Feel of the application, I'm just doing some changes on the components, like removing boarders, changing fonts, etc.
The problem is that the ComboBox apparently has no property that can do this kind of thing with its gradient feel.

The question is: Anyone knows a way to remove the 'gradient' of the ComboBox without changing the look and feel?

Thank you!

Comment: what's here `gradient`?

Comment: Can you post a picture of how it should look like?